# How can run PDO database connection in PHP with OOP structure?

Tags: php, database, pdo, connection

Consider the following PHP coding...

```html
<?php
class MyPDO extends PDO{

    const PARAM_host='localhost';
    const PARAM_port='3306';
    const PARAM_db_name='test';
    const PARAM_user='root';
    const PARAM_db_pass='';
    public $con;

    public function __construct(){

        $user = MyPDO::PARAM_user;
        $password = MyPDO::PARAM_db_pass;

        $dsn = 'mysql:host='.MyPDO::PARAM_host.';port='.MyPDO::PARAM_port.';dbname='.MyPDO::PARAM_db_name;

        try {
            $con = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
            echo "connected successfully";
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }

    } //End of constructor function


    public function fetch(){
        // Fetch Data form Table
        try{
            /*** The SQL SELECT statement ***/
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM student";
            foreach ($con->query($sql) as $row)
                {
                print $row['Roll'] .' - '. $row['Name'] . '<br />';
                }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
            }
    }//End of function Fetch

} //End of class

$obj = new MyPDO;
$obj->fetch();
?>
```

If i run the above coding following error message is showing:-

Notice: Undefined variable: con in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\11.php on line 33

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\11.php on line 33

What will be the change of the above code segment?

Comment: `$con = ...` should be `$this->con` and in all the functions within this class, you should reference it as `$this->con`, and **not** as `$con`. Look as Jonathon's answer, that pretty much sums it up.

Answer (score 4):

Since `con` is a member variable, use this syntax to refer to it:

```
$this->con = ... 
$this->con->query($sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in a `Class` object context, use this instead:

```
$this->con = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$this->con->query("Your sql query");
```